# In alfresco document property page title is not getting displayed

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

After uploading document in alfresco site I am clicking edit properties,
but the title at header is not getting displayed properly.

please refer below attached image to understand issue.

Regarding this I have checked the logs in browser console as well as server logs at repository level.

But there is no error.

So I am not getting how to resolve this issue.

Also I have observed that if we open document and then click on edit properties, then its getting displayed properly.

Please suggest me, what will be the issue and how to tackle[image] this type of problems.

Comment: Can you please share your  share form config code ,there may some mistake in your form configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a custom form?

If you have defined it  in  share-custom-config.xml you could insert a template to display the name too.

EDIT:

It might work this way, i havent tried it:

in your form definition

```
<appearance>
     <field id="my:nameType" label="Title Type" mandatory="true" read-only="true">
      <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/custom.ftl">
      <control-param name="titleType">My Type</control-param></control>

                </field>
 </appearance>
```

you should implement you custom.ftl to display what you want